# Suppress Fancy header and footer on first page only.

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

How to suppress the fancy header and footer on the first page? On other pages, they should be visible.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Put `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the beginning of your document. This will only affect the first page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Top Left}
\fancyhead[C]{Top Center}
\fancyhead[R]{Top Right}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{Bottom Left}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{Bottom Right}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

Lorem ipsum.

\newpage

Lorem ipsum to you, too, brother.

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of two pages]

Note that if you use `\maketitle`, you'll have to put the `\thispagestyle{empty}` *after* the `\maketitle` because `\maketitle` triggers a `\thispagestyle{plain}`, which is the standard page style with only the page number at the bottom.

If you want any other page style on your first page, you can put in anything else instead of `empty`, of course.

Comment: I found this trying to do the opposite, **including** the fancy header on the first page.  I had no idea that `\maketitle` triggered a `\thispagestyle{plain}`!  Good to know!

Comment: \thispagestyle{empty} will also supress footnotes. How to disable fancy header, but keep footnotes?

Comment: @nagylzs If I add a footnote to the document from this answer, footnotes aren’t suppressed. I’d suggest you ask a new question with a MWE to reproduce your problem.

Comment: And how can I suppress only the header on the first page ?

Answer (score 8):

Move the preamble for header and footer into the document after the `\newpage` where you would like it to start.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
%\thispagestyle{empty}

Lorem ipsum.

\newpage

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Top Left}
\fancyhead[C]{Top Center}
\fancyhead[R]{Top Right}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{Bottom Left}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{Bottom Right}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

Lorem ipsum to you, too, brother.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This would only be helpful if the first page doesn't spill over to the next naturally. That is, if you can control the break to page two manually.

Comment: @Werner Your explanation 'over my head,' for I am a beginner. My problem, was to have the footer information start on page 4 in an article document class. Maybe I should have created a new question? Any advise for me would be gladly accepted.

Comment: This helped me to do the inverse of what OP asked, that is, suppress headers/footers after the first page.