# How to avoid header and footer on first page?

Tags: header-footer, titles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suppress Fancy header and footer on first page only.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23766/suppress-fancy-header-and-footer-on-first-page-only)

I'm using header and footer but I want to avoid on very first page since it is title page. How can i implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\thispagestyle{empty}`  will do the trick