# LyX: remove header in specific page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, lyx

My thesis is sectioned in Parts -> Sections -> Subsections.

Currently I am printing the part name on the header of each page. However, I would like to remove the header completely on the first page of each part.

My LyX preamble header definition:

```
\let\Oldpart\part
\newcommand{\parttitle}{}
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\Oldpart{#1}\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}}

\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \parttitle}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23766/suppress-fancy-header-and-footer-on-first-page-only

Comment: I don't think so. I only want to remove the header, not header and footer, and it's not for the first page of the document, but for the first page of every part.

Comment: @user29762 Which document class are you using?

Comment: @e-birk article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
\renewcommand\part[1]{%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \Oldpart{#1}\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

My first solution would be to switch the document class from `article` to `report` (or derivates thereof). For a thesis or a similar large document, the class `report` has a more appropriate formatting. Especially, it puts each *part title* on a separate blank page, i.e., more or less what you want.

My second solution would be to use

```
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\Oldpart{#1}\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

You might need to precede each part with a page break.