# Removing the footer on the first page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Im using fancyhdr to customise an article

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

\rhead{Overleaf Proof of Concept}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Seite \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% no line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\maketitle

\section{Lorem ipsum}
```

I get the wanted result on all the pages but the first.

On the first I have the page number in the middle of the footer.
On all the others I have on the right the text "Seite" followed by the current page and the total.

How can I get rid of the page number on the first page? Or how can apply the footer style (but not the header) on the first page?

Comment: `\thispagestyle{zzz}` where you use fancyhdr to define a page style `zzz` with a head but blank foot

Comment: On the first page you have implicitly a ``\thispagestyle{plain}`` that produces the unwanted result. Using ``\thispagestyle{empty}`` will remove both header and footer on the target page.

Comment: @Jhor Thanks! Post it as an answer so that I can accept it...

Comment: It appears now that this question is a duplicate and already has a detailed answer on  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23766.